# JavaScript card PAN check digit Luhn verification

Tags: javascript, credit-card, luhn

I've used the code from the link below to try and validate a credit card, however I'm not getting an alert when I submit a the wrong data in the field.

[Strip spaces before performing Luhn check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956467/strip-spaces-before-performing-luhn-check.com)

my form is as follows:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action=""> 

<p>Select credit card:
   <select tabindex="11" id="CardType"> 
      <option value="AmEx">American Express</option> 
    <option value="CarteBlanche">Carte Blanche</option> 
    <option value="DinersClub">Diners Club</option> 
    <option value="Discover">Discover</option> 
    <option value="EnRoute">enRoute</option> 
    <option value="JCB">JCB</option> 
    <option value="Maestro">Maestro</option> 
    <option value="MasterCard">MasterCard</option> 
    <option value="Solo">Solo</option> 
    <option value="Switch">Switch</option> 
    <option value="Visa">Visa</option> 
    <option value="VisaElectron">Visa Electron</option> 
    <option value="LaserCard">Laser</option> 
  </select> 
</p>

<p>
Enter number:
 <input type="text" id="CardNumber" maxlength="24" size="24" />
  <input type="submit" id="submitbutton" onsubmit="Validate(Luhn);" />  
</p> 

</form>
```

Maybe I'm using the wrong code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move `onsubmit="Validate(Luhn);"`

to the form tag and pass the form

Like this - note I pass the form and find the number from the form. 
I also moved the test and return false/return true around

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VqXss/

```
function Validate(theForm) {
  var Luhn = theForm.CardNumber.value;
  var LuhnDigit = parseInt(Luhn.substring(Luhn.length-1,Luhn.length));
  var LuhnLess = Luhn.substring(0,Luhn.length-1);
  if (Calculate(LuhnLess)!=parseInt(LuhnDigit)) {
    alert("\n\nYou have mis-typed your card number! \nPlease check and correct.\n\n")   
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return Validate(this)">
```

Comment: thanks for your response...i copied the above code however the form seems to just submit regardless.

Comment: you are welcome... Now see my other answer to your submit button issue

Answer (score 1):

I came to this question looking for online card PAN validator in javascript that can be safely used to [verify PAN check digit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm#Verification_of_the_check_digit) without risk of malicious intercept on server.

There are plenty of javascript Luhn implementations at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Luhn_test_of_credit_card_numbers#JavaScript and https://sites.google.com/site/abapexamples/javascript/luhn-validation.

Here is typical implementation:

```
var LuhnCheck = (function()
{
    var luhnArr = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
    return function(str)
    {
        var counter = 0;
        var incNum;
        var odd = false;
        var temp = String(str).replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
        if ( temp.length == 0)
            return false;
        for (var i = temp.length-1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            incNum = parseInt(temp.charAt(i), 10);
            counter += (odd = !odd)? incNum : luhnArr[incNum];
        }
        return (counter%10 == 0);
    }
})();
```

And by googling for "luhn jsfiddle" I've found another ready to use robust online validator:

http://jsfiddle.net/silvinci/84bru/light/